# Given $n$ pickets and $k$ colors count in how many the fence can be painted

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

We are given a picket fence with $n$ pickets and we are given $k$ colors to paint it.

No more than two neighbouring pickets should share same color.
In how many **different** ways can we paint the fence ?

For example if we have $2$ pickets and $4$ colors we have $16$ possible ways of painting the fence.

$4$ choices if every picket is painted the same color.

And then $4$ choices for the first picket * $3$ remaining choices for the second picket.

In total : $4$+$4*3 = 4 + 12 = 16$

My question is how can I build a recurrence relation for this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the number of ways be $C(n,k)$. Then the number of ways when the first picket **cannot** use a specific colour is $\frac{k-1}{k}C(n,k)$.

Then, for $n\ge 3$:-

> If the first two pickets are coloured differently

The number of ways is $k \times\frac{k-1}{k}C(n-1,k)=(k-1)C(n-1,k)$.

> If the first two pickets are coloured the same

The number of ways is $k \times 1\times \frac{k-1}{k}C(n-2,k)=(k-1)C(n-2,k)$.

$$C(n,k)=(k-1)\biggl(C(n-1,k)+C(n-2,k)\biggr).$$